# Nightcrawler in X2 and Apocalypse

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, continuity

In X2, it appears that Jean and Storm don't know who Nightcrawler is. In Apocalypse, they do. By my understanding, Apocalypse was set in an earlier chronological time reference. What's going on?

Comment: *Days of Future Past* changed the timeline

Comment: Welcome to the site, Christine. I've cleaned up your post - I've removed the chatty bit that isn't really part of the question, and tweaked some pronouns ("this" is a bad word for clarity's sake). If I've inadvertently deleted some key element, feel free to add it back.

Answer (score 13):

In Days of Future Past, Magneto and Xavier, with the help of Kitty Pryde, send Wolverine's consciousness back in time to the 70's to change history.

He succeeds, and creates a new timeline.

X2 is in the original timeline. *Apocalypse* is set in this new timeline.